# windows store: register event handler "SizeChanged"

Tags: windows-store-apps, handler, splash-screen

I want to follow a tutorial for a splash screen for a Windows 8.1 app.

You can find the tutorial at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868191.aspx). At some point, it says

> Make sure to register your Window.SizeChanged handler (ExtendedSplash_OnResize in the example) in your class constructor

I don't know how I can do it. What should I do?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

edit:

Maybe it's related to this issue. At some point the tutorial say to add these namespace into the file in which I write the constructor:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using SplashScreenExample.Common;
```

but I can't add the last one, because Common namespace does not exists (only SplashScreenExample.Pages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class constructor, try using something like this to register the event -

```
Window.Current.SizeChanged += new WindowSizeChangedEventHandler(ExtendedSplash_OnResize);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it because it's in the tutorial, but I obtain following error: Error 1 The name 'ExtendedSplash_OnResize' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Did you make sure you implemented the method ExtendedSplash_OnResize in class ExtendedSplash?

Comment: No, I have not these methods. I've tried to add a simple "void ExtendedSplash_OnResize() {} " in my class but I obtain the following error: Error 1 No overload for 'ExtendedSplash_OnResize' matches delegate 'Windows.UI.Xaml.WindowSizeChangedEventHandler'. Ho can I add it correctly?

Comment: See step 7 of your tutorial.